# Graphic card motherboard keeps beeping as soon as it boots up and the display doesn't come on

Tags: windows, graphics

My computer specifications
Intel motherboard
Core i3
8gb ram
500 power supply
1tb hard
Nvidia geforce gt 630 graphic card

Comment: Always? When did this start? Did you look up the beep code?